# how to create a global route prefix in sails?

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js

I just recently started using sails and nodejs.

I was wondering, is there an easy way to create a global prefix using the configuration available in Sails? Or would I need to bring in another library?

I found the blueprint prefix configuration in config/controller.js. It seems there ought to be an easy way to do this since the application already partially supports it...

I'm trying to get something like /api/v1 in front of all routes I have for my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can set the prefix property to `/api/v1` in config/controller.js . But note that this will only add the prefix to the blueprint routes (those automatically generated by Sails).

Thus, with the prefix set to `/api/v1` and the route `/some`, it could be accessed at uri `/api/v1/some`.

But if you declare your routes like this: `"post /someEndPoint": {controller: "someController", action: "someAction"}`, the prefix does nothing.

In this case you must write them manually like this: `post /api/v1/someEndPoint` and set to false the `actions` property from `config/controller.js` (at least in production) to turn off automatically generated routes for every action within your controllers.

**@EDIT 08.08.2014**

The above applies to versions of `Sails.Js` smaller than *v0.10*. Because I don't work anymore with Sails, I don't know what applies now to the current version of the framework.

**@EDIT 14.08.2014**

For versions of sails.js >= 0.10, the configuration file where the prefix can be set is `config/blueprints.js`. It has the same functionality as had for older versions.

**@Edit 07.09.2015**

As far as I know, the framework doesn't support a global prefix for manually defined routes, but since you can still use javascript in your config files (since the configuration files are nodeJs modules and not JSON files), you can easily tweak this functionality to work as you need to.

Supposing that the `prefix` property is set to `/api` in your blueprints config file, you can have this code in your routes.

```
var blueprintConfig = require('./blueprints');

var ROUTE_PREFIX = blueprintConfig.blueprints.prefix || "";

// add global prefix to manually defined routes
function addGlobalPrefix(routes) {
  var paths = Object.keys(routes),
      newRoutes = {};

  if(ROUTE_PREFIX === "") {
    return routes;
  }

  paths.forEach(function(path) {
    var pathParts = path.split(" "),
        uri = pathParts.pop(),
        prefixedURI = "", newPath = "";

      prefixedURI = ROUTE_PREFIX + uri;

      pathParts.push(prefixedURI);

      newPath = pathParts.join(" ");
      // construct the new routes
      newRoutes[newPath] = routes[path];
  });

  return newRoutes;
};

module.exports.routes = addGlobalPrefix({

  /***************************************************************************
   *                                                                          *
   * Make the view located at `views/homepage.ejs` (or `views/homepage.jade`, *
   * etc. depending on your default view engine) your home page.              *
   *                                                                          *
   * (Alternatively, remove this and add an `index.html` file in your         *
   * `assets` directory)                                                      *
   *                                                                          *
   ***************************************************************************/

  // '/': {
  //   view: 'homepage'
  // },

  /***************************************************************************
   *                                                                          *
   * Custom routes here...                                                    *
   *                                                                          *
   *  If a request to a URL doesn't match any of the custom routes above, it  *
   * is matched against Sails route blueprints. See `config/blueprints.js`    *
   * for configuration options and examples.                                  *
   *                                                                          *
   ***************************************************************************/

  'post /fake': 'FakeController.create',
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But that's kinda what I was hoping to avoid...I was *hoping* Sails had a simple configuration that allowed that (separate from the blueprints). But it seems i may have to manually configure it...

Comment: @harmlessdragon yes, I had the same problem and I thought the prefix should solve it, but didn't. So you have to manually write your prefix for every route, I did it too... I know is kinda messy, but I saw that there was some discussion on this, to add the prefix to those routes too. The good part is that your routes are in the same file and it will be easiere to change them when they're going to add the "expected functionality" on prefix

Comment: This won't work on v10 sail.js now, as config/controllers are deprecated

Comment: @KitHo Thanks, I've edited my answer. I don't work with sails anymore and thus I don't know how the current version is working. Maybe another answer should be added, explaining how the current version works.

Comment: If you use sails.js v >= 0.10, you should now setup the prefix in config/blueprints.js. As per a comment in that file, "this only applies to blueprint autoroutes, not manual routes from `sails.config.routes`".

Comment: @user635090 Thanks! I've updated my answer to be visible for the users that will not read your comment.

Comment: is it possible to add a prefix to all explicit routes?

Comment: @eAbi Thanks for such simplified trick. I was wondering how to include all that code to a stand alone module like a service in the /api/services folder so that in the routes files just import the module and add module.exports.routes = addGlobalPrefix({. And not to have that code in the routes file in order to make it cleaner.

Comment: @Lexynux I think you're complicating the matters if you do that. I think it's more cleaner to have that code in that routes file because the addGlobalPrefix it's just a tiny helper to add the prefix to your manually defined routes. When you'll want to debug something you'll have the code right there. Beware though, the helper will add global prefix too all of your routes, even if you have views on your server. Use that helper if you use the sails server only as a REST Api service.

Comment: Method of `@Edit 07.09.2015` still working fine from 2018 (Sails 1.0)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.12.x, this is located in config/blueprints.js on line 100. The same rules apply as previously mentioned. The prefix only applies to the blueprint autoroutes, not manually create routes in config/routes.js.

`/***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * An optional mount path for all blueprint routes on a controller,         *
  * including 'rest', 'actions', and 'shortcuts'. This allows you to take    *
  * advantage of blueprint routing, even if you need to namespace your API   *
  * methods.                                                                 *
  *                                                                          *
  * (NOTE: This only applies to blueprint autoroutes, not manual routes from *
  * 'sails.config.routes')                                                   *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/
  // prefix: '',`  <----- line 100 in config/blueprints.js

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly define your routes in `config/routes.js`, then try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797788/5326603