# Is it possible to have sails.js APIs under /api rather than /?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've created an API using the following command:

`$ sails generate api blog`

Which works fine, but if I wanted to be able to use the URL `/blog` for providing the front end HTML using Angular, I can't.

Is it possible to move all APIs to `/api`, place static files and more routes which need more server-side code above the route to the Angular app, and redirect all other URLs to my Angular app, where I can organise routing there? For example:

1. A user accesses `/blog`, which causes Sails.js to load the default template, which includes Angular in the `<script>` tag.
2. Angular reads the URL as `/blog`, so downloads the template `/templates/blog.html`, a static file in the 'assets' folder.
3. The template includes requests from `/api`, like `/api/blog/page/1`.

Comment: Found a similar question asked, [global route prefix in salisjs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665272/how-to-create-a-global-route-prefix-in-sails

Comment: There is no 'config/controllers.js' file @Nindaff, maybe it was removed?

Comment: Ya i don't what version you are using, but i guess 0.10 and greater you want to checkout, `config/blueprints.js`

Comment: @Nindaff I'm using `npm install -g sails` to install the generator, so why would it be an old version?

Comment: @Nindaff I'll try it using 'config/blueprints.js'

Comment: @Nindaff That worked, thanks. I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665272/how-to-create-a-global-route-prefix-in-sails), but the general gist is:

Find your `controllers.js` (older versions of sails.js) or `blueprints.js` (sails.js versions since 0.10) and load it in to your text editor and scroll down to the following line (line 100 in the default file as of March 2015):

`// prefix: '',`

Uncomment that line, inserting your desired prefix URL in, like so:

`prefix: '/api',`

Ensuring that the URL does not have a forward slash at the end, otherwise accessing `/api/<blah>/<blah>` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply you can do it by setting a blueprint prefix at `config/blueprint.js`. Like changing the following line

```
// prefix : ''
```

to

```
prefix: '/api'
```

It would add this prefix to each and every blueprint api routes. May be this would be sufficient for you. But there is option for you to more fine tune.

Suppose you have a `X` controller and a `Y` controller. You want to use prefix `/apix` to `X` controller but `/apiy` to `Y` controller. Then you have to change `X` controller in following way,

```
module.exports = {
  _config: {
    prefix: '/apix'
  }
}
```

and `Y` controller in following way,

```
module.exports = {
  _config: {
    prefix: '/apiy'
  }
}
```

Summary is if you want all your blueprint api to behave in some way then change configuration in `config/blueprint.js` but if you want some specific blueprint api to behave some way then add `_config` attribute to that controller value of which would be same as blueprint configuration. It would override the global configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but this appears to be long-winded, so I'm sticking to the answer above. If you want your APIs to appear under a different prefix for each, then this is the way to do it, but overall, the other method does the job fine.