# How do I namespace my api in sails.js like so /api/v1?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I want to namespace my api requests to /api/v1/ Maybe later some also to api/v2/. How can I do this efficiently in sails.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is three ways of doing this.

1st: blueprints

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.blueprints.html
[how to create a global route prefix in sails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665272/how-to-create-a-global-route-prefix-in-sails)

```
prefix: '/api'
```

or `restPrefix: '/api'`

[how to create a global route prefix in sails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665272/how-to-create-a-global-route-prefix-in-sails)

2nd: in each controller adding

```
_config: { prefix: '/api/v2' }
```

3rd: configure it in the routes

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Routes

```
'/api/v2/': 'FooController',
```

Comment: Which is the most recommended?

Answer (score 2):

Whereas other frameworks allow you to nest a block or closure, you can't do so in Sails. My approach is to use a variable that holds the prefix and apply it (after evaluating the string) to each route object key as such:

```
const prefix = '/my/api/v2';

module.exports = {
  [`GET ${prefix}/where/ever/you/want`]: { ... },

  [`POST ${prefix}/some/where/nice`]: { ... },
}
```

The above uses **string interpolation** with **ES6**. If you do not have that, just use string **concatenation**: `['GET ' + prefix + '/where/ever']: { ... }`.